# Accessing JSON items in python

Tags: python, json

I'm attempting to iterate through each section and print out the information but I keep getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
as my error.
Here is my data:

```
  [
   {
      "_id":"5be584e807b6f93c2cee00c4",
      "updated":1541785331000,
      "series":null,
      "price":11,
      "site":"cigar_auctioneer",
      "d_no":null,
      "wrapper_code":"OSC",
      "shape":"petite corona",
      "link":"https://www.cigarauctioneer.com/tatuaje-tattoo-needles-5-cigars/item-61689?auctionnum=3058524",
      "item_id":61689,
      "path":"tatuaje-tattoo-needles-5-cigars/item-61689?auctionnum=3058524",
      "id":3058524,
      "size":"4 1/2 x 38",
      "sku":"CI-TTA-NEEDMZ-75",
      "closes":"2018-11-12T23:13:00.000Z",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "number":null,
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Needles",
      "package":"pack",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"oscuro",
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":5,
      "closed":1542064380000,
      "type":"pack",
      "quantity":1
   },
   {
      "_id":"5be4221207b6f92342f0ae23",
      "updated":1541785907000,
      "series":null,
      "price":39,
      "site":"cigar_auctioneer",
      "d_no":null,
      "wrapper_code":"OSC",
      "shape":"torpedo",
      "link":"https://www.cigarauctioneer.com/tatuaje-tattoo-bonita-10-pk-cigars/item-53476?auctionnum=3052556",
      "item_id":53476,
      "path":"tatuaje-tattoo-bonita-10-pk-cigars/item-53476?auctionnum=3052556",
      "id":3052556,
      "size":"6 1/4 x 52",
      "sku":"CI-TTA-BONM10PK-75",
      "closes":"2018-11-12T03:22:00.000Z",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "number":null,
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Bonita",
      "package":"pack",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"oscuro",
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":5,
      "closed":1541992920000,
      "type":"pack",
      "quantity":10
   },
   {
      "_id":"5bde7e2a07b6f92cc36a75fb",
      "origin":"nicaragua",
      "updated":1541693111000,
      "series":null,
      "price":null,
      "site":"cbid",
      "d_no":null,
      "number":null,
      "shape":"robusto",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "link":"https://www.cigarbid.com/a/tatuaje-tattoo-caballero/3030156/",
      "path":"a/tatuaje-tattoo-caballero/3030156/",
      "id":3030156,
      "unit":"box of 50",
      "size":"5 x 50",
      "sku":"TAT-PM-1008",
      "closes":"2018-11-11T04:58:00.000Z",
      "strength":"medium",
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero",
      "package":"box of 50",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"ecuador habano",
      "exdata":{
         "skuId":"TAT-PM-1008",
         "list":"PLP>Search",
         "isImpression":true,
         "lot":{
            "category":"Free Fall Cigar Auction",
            "closes":"2018-11-10T23:58:00-05:00",
            "lotId":3030156,
            "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero (Robusto) (5.0\"x50) Box of 50",
            "engine":"DutchLoop",
            "status":"Open",
            "opens":"2018-11-04T00:13:00-04:00"
         },
         "fullName":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero (50)",
         "type":"Handmade Cigars",
         "id":154551,
         "pack":"Box of 50"
      },
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":null,
      "closed":1541912280000,
      "type":"box of 50",
      "quantity":50
   },
   {
      "_id":"5be2d68207b6f90b492ae0fd",
      "updated":1541786158000,
      "series":null,
      "price":195,
      "site":"cigar_auctioneer",
      "d_no":null,
      "wrapper_code":"OSC",
      "shape":"torpedo",
      "link":"https://www.cigarauctioneer.com/tatuaje-tattoo-bonito-cigars/item-45795?auctionnum=3045899",
      "item_id":45795,
      "path":"tatuaje-tattoo-bonito-cigars/item-45795?auctionnum=3045899",
      "id":3045899,
      "size":"6 1/4 x 52",
      "sku":"CI-TTA-BONM-75",
      "closes":"2018-11-11T02:45:00.000Z",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "number":null,
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Bonito",
      "package":"box",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"oscuro",
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":1,
      "closed":1541904300000,
      "type":"box",
      "quantity":50
   },
   {
      "_id":"5be07b8d07b6f95b9a151a83",
      "origin":"nicaragua",
      "updated":1541787982000,
      "series":null,
      "price":3,
      "site":"cbid",
      "d_no":null,
      "number":null,
      "shape":"robusto",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "link":"https://www.cigarbid.com/a/tatuaje-tattoo-caballero/3029330/",
      "path":"a/tatuaje-tattoo-caballero/3029330/",
      "id":3029330,
      "unit":"single",
      "size":"5 x 50",
      "sku":"TAT-PM-1001",
      "closes":"2018-11-10T04:48:00.000Z",
      "strength":"medium",
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero",
      "package":"single",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"ecuador habano",
      "exdata":{
         "skuId":"TAT-PM-1001",
         "list":"PLP>Search",
         "isImpression":true,
         "lot":{
            "category":"Cigar Singles",
            "closes":"2018-11-09T23:48:00-05:00",
            "minimumOffer":3,
            "lotId":3029330,
            "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero (Robusto) (5.0\"x50) Single",
            "engine":"English",
            "status":"Open",
            "units":2,
            "opens":"2018-11-05T12:00:00-05:00"
         },
         "fullName":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero (robusto) (Single)",
         "type":"Handmade Cigars",
         "id":161996,
         "pack":"Single"
      },
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":2,
      "closed":1541825280000,
      "type":"single",
      "quantity":1
   },
   {
      "_id":"5be190b607b6f9711c751df4",
      "updated":1541786729000,
      "series":null,
      "price":19,
      "site":"cigar_auctioneer",
      "d_no":null,
      "wrapper_code":"OSC",
      "shape":"torpedo",
      "link":"https://www.cigarauctioneer.com/tatuaje-tattoo-bonita-5-pk-cigars/item-53475?auctionnum=3048388",
      "item_id":53475,
      "path":"tatuaje-tattoo-bonita-5-pk-cigars/item-53475?auctionnum=3048388",
      "id":3048388,
      "size":"6 1/4 x 52",
      "sku":"CI-TTA-BONM5PK-75",
      "closes":"2018-11-10T03:05:00.000Z",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "number":null,
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Bonita",
      "package":"pack",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"oscuro",
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":5,
      "closed":1541819100000,
      "type":"pack",
      "quantity":5
   },
   {
      "_id":"5be08ae107b6f95e788e0999",
      "origin":"nicaragua",
      "updated":1541786947000,
      "series":null,
      "price":14.5,
      "site":"cbid",
      "d_no":null,
      "number":null,
      "shape":"robusto",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "link":"https://www.cigarbid.com/a/tatuaje-tattoo-caballero/3025943/",
      "path":"a/tatuaje-tattoo-caballero/3025943/",
      "id":3025943,
      "unit":"pack of 5",
      "size":"5 x 50",
      "sku":"TAT-PM-1003",
      "closes":"2018-11-10T00:58:00.000Z",
      "strength":"medium",
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero",
      "package":"pack of 5",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"ecuador habano",
      "exdata":{
         "skuId":"TAT-PM-1003",
         "list":"PLP>Search",
         "isImpression":true,
         "lot":{
            "category":"5-Packs of Cigars",
            "closes":"2018-11-09T19:58:00-05:00",
            "minimumOffer":14.5,
            "lotId":3025943,
            "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero (Robusto) (5.0\"x50) Pack of 5",
            "engine":"English",
            "status":"Open",
            "units":9,
            "opens":"2018-11-05T12:35:00-05:00"
         },
         "fullName":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero - 5-Pack",
         "type":"Handmade Cigars",
         "id":154550,
         "pack":"Pack of 5"
      },
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":9,
      "closed":1541811480000,
      "type":"pack of 5",
      "quantity":5
   },
   {
      "_id":"5be18ff707b6f9711c751d87",
      "updated":1541786468000,
      "series":null,
      "price":12,
      "site":"cigar_auctioneer",
      "d_no":null,
      "wrapper_code":"OSC",
      "shape":"robusto",
      "link":"https://www.cigarauctioneer.com/tatuaje-tattoo-caballero-5-pack-cigars/item-48230?auctionnum=3051568",
      "item_id":48230,
      "path":"tatuaje-tattoo-caballero-5-pack-cigars/item-48230?auctionnum=3051568",
      "id":3051568,
      "size":"5 x 50",
      "sku":"CI-TTA-CABM5PK-75",
      "closes":"2018-11-10T00:17:00.000Z",
      "is_cigar":true,
      "number":null,
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Caballero",
      "package":"pack",
      "vintage":null,
      "wrapper":"oscuro",
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":1,
      "closed":1541809020000,
      "type":"pack",
      "quantity":5
   }
]
```

And here is my code attempting to access it

```
import os
import time
import re
import json
import requests, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with requests.Session() as se:
        searchTerm = "tatuaje+tattoo"
        se.headers = {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36",
            "Referer": "https://herf.io/bids?search="+searchTerm,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
        }
        data = [
            "search="+searchTerm,
            "types=",
            "sites=",
        ]

        cookies = {
            "Cookie": "connect.sid=s%3ANYNh5s6LzCVWY8yE9Gra8lxj9OGHPAK_.vGiBmTXvfF4iDScBF94YOXFDmC80PQxY%2FX9FLQ23hYI"}

        url = "https://herf.io/bids/search/open"

        price = "https://herf.io/bids/search/stats"

        openAuctions = "https://herf.io/bids/search/open"

        closedAuctions = "https://herf.io/bids/search/closed"

        #req = se.post(price,data="&".join(data),cookies=cookies,verify=False)
        reqAuctions = se.post(openAuctions,data="&".join(data),cookies=cookies,verify=False)
        #str = req.json()
        strAuctions = reqAuctions.json()

        print(strAuctions['_id'])
        print(strAuctions['link'])
```

I'm assuming the issue is the fact that the top level doesn't have a dict key?  Looking around other people are talking about using for loops iterating through the top level dicts but I'm not sure how to access without it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is right. The top level is an array, not a dictionary. If you just want the first entry you can do

```
print(strAuctions[0]['_id'])
print(strAuctions[0]['link'])
```

To output information for each entry use

```
for auction in strAuctions:
    print(auction['_id'])
    print(auction['link'])
```

Comment: Thanks! this is as simple of an approach as I was hoping for!  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

use that code
print(strAuctions.keys())
with this code you are see all the keys 
if you want to use it you can try for loop

Comment: it throws AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys' error

Comment: strAuctions[0].keys()

Answer (score 0):

Since the outermost element in the object you have is a `list`, you should access it using indexes and then use key to access the `dictionary` elements.

Example:

```
list1=[
   {
      "_id":"5be584e807b6f93c2cee00c4",
      "updated":1541785331000,
      "series":11,
      "price":11,
      "site":"cigar_auctioneer",
      "d_no":11,
      "wrapper_code":"OSC",
      "shape":"petite corona",
      "link":"https://www.cigarauctioneer.com/tatuaje-tattoo-needles-5-cigars/item-61689?auctionnum=3058524",
      "item_id":61689,
      "path":"tatuaje-tattoo-needles-5-cigars/item-61689?auctionnum=3058524",
      "id":3058524,
      "size":"4 1/2 x 38",
      "sku":"CI-TTA-NEEDMZ-75",
      "closes":"2018-11-12T23:13:00.000Z",
      "is_cigar":True,
      "number":[1,2,3],
      "name":"Tatuaje Tattoo Needles",
      "package":"pack",
      "vintage":11,
      "wrapper":"oscuro",
      "state":"open",
      "num_units":5,
      "closed":1542064380000,
      "type":"pack",
      "quantity":1
   }]
```

To access the quantity value of 1, you can do this:

```
list1[0]['quantity']
```

If your values in the dictionary contains list you need to further access using indexes.

To access elements in the list under the key `number`, you should do this

```
list1[0]['number'][0]
```

where 0 refers to the index

Note: modified original data to give the explanation